# Laravel: Redirecting from javascript in a Blade file` without using a route name

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using a blade file and need to redirect from Javascript but I won't be redirecting to a path inside my app -- I will be directing to another site.  How would I go about doing that since I can't use `URL::to`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

location.href = 'enter url here'